# Saving a newly-created object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a Rails controller code

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.random_hash = generate_random_hash(params[:post][:title])
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
  end
end
```

Should the first two lines of the definition be put inside `if @post.save` or not? If the post is not saved, will the Post object created by `Post.new` still be put in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > Should the first two lines of the definition be put inside if `@post.save` or not?

   Most certainly not. If you change it to the following as you suggest:

   ```
   def create
     if @post.save
       @post = Post.new(params[:post])
       @post.random_hash = generate_random_hash(params[:post][:title])
       format.html { redirect_to @post }
     else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
     end
   end
   ```

   Then it won't work at all. There is no `@post` to call `save` on.
2. > If the post is not saved, will the `Post` object created by `Post.new` still be put in the database?

   Of course not. That's what saving does: saves the object in the database. If you don't call `save` on the `Post` object, or the `save` returns `false` (which would happen because a validation failed), the object was *not* stored in the database. `Post.new` simply creates a new `Post` object in-memory—it doesn't touch the database at all.